# Extracting a pattern from string which contains filename

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to extract  uid suffix from below string. I am trying pattern .But I get no match found.

**Input**:exportDocumentInfo_29510309-5673-4c20-83bd-6d2303c21016-0.txt

**uid**:  29510309-5673-4c20-83bd-6d2303c21016

**suffix**: 0

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("exportDocumentInfo_*-*.txt");
        String mydata = "exportDocumentInfo_29510309-5673-4c20-83bd-6d2303c21016-0.txt
";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace each `*` with `(.*)`. Also, remove the linebreak before `";`, otherwise, the program will not compile. The result should look similar to this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Pattern pattern = 
                Pattern.compile("exportDocumentInfo_(.*)-(.*).txt");
        final String mydata =
                "exportDocumentInfo_29510309-5673-4c20-83bd-6d2303c21016-0.txt";
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/oba0Os)

Answer (score 1):

You need a pattern like `exportDocumentInfo_([\w-]+)-([0-9]+)\.txt`, to use groups you need the parenthesis to capture the content, and let only digits in the last group

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("exportDocumentInfo_([\w-]+)-([0-9]+)\.txt");
    String mydata = "exportDocumentInfo_29510309-5673-4c20-83bd-6d2303c21016-0.txt";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }

}
```

[<kbd>>> Regex demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/qA0pSi/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another regex that solves the problem (just replace it in your code):

```
exportDocumentInfo_(.*)-(.*).txt
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dIWkr6/1/)